# Wordpress: Get images of current post

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

i'm trying to get all images of a post using this method:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);  

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, ATTACHMENT_IMAGE_SIZE );
        }
        return $images;
    }
```

unfortunately, this will get all images ever uploaded, not just those associated to the current post. i found this [post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-thumbnails-of-images-attached-to-a-post?) using *get_children*, but it doesn't work either. any ideas?

ps: i running the code when a post created/updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
<?php 
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,             
        ) );

        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
                $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
            }

        }

?>
```

Read more [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-get-all-post-attachments-in-wordpress-except-for-featured-image/).

Make sure $post->ID is not empty.
If this is still not working you can try Extracting Images from the Page / Post  content. More details [here](http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/extract-images-from-wordpress-post/)

Comment: checking whether $post->ID is empty did the job. thank you very much!

Comment: How does this answer "unfortunately, this will get all images ever uploaded, not just those associated to the current post"? I checked and this does not return the images currently IN USE by the specified post.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it by adding a hook in your `functions.php` to fire after post/page has been created/updated and wrap your code inside that function as given bellow

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'after_post_save' );
function after_post_save( $post_id ) {
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type($post_id) ) // check if this is a post
    {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post_id
        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $images[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, ATTACHMENT_IMAGE_SIZE );
            }
            return $images; // End of function and nothing happens
        }
    }
}
```

**Remember**, basically it'll do nothing by returning the `$images` array at the end of your function unless you do something with the images.

**Note:** The `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function returns an array which contains

```
[0] => url // the src of image
[1] => width // the width
[2] => height // the height
```

So in your `$images` array it will contain something like this

```
array(
    [0] => array([0] => url, [1] => width, [2] => height), // first image
    [1] => array([0] => url, [1] => width, 2] => height) // second image
);
```